# Deleting a record in a Database

Tags: php

i made a program that will delete record in database and it is working but the program automatically delete the record without confirmation. I want my program to confirm first before deleting, how am i going to do that?

Content function code:

```
 //*********************************************************************
 function Content() 
{
    if(isset($_POST['btnAdd']))  //if in case 'Add Entry' button is click 
    {
        return DataEntryForm('');
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['btnSave'])) //if in case 'Save' button is click during adding new entry or editing
    {
        if($_POST['uname']=='')
        {
            return saveRecord();
        }
        else
        {
            return updateRecord();
        }
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['edituname'])) //if in case 'Edit' is click 
    {
        return DataEntryForm('Edit');
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['deluname']))  //if in case 'Delete' is click 
    {
        return deleteRecord();
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['btnSearch'])) //if in case 'Search' is click 
    {
        return viewRecord();
    }
    else
    {
        return viewRecord('');
    }

}
```

Delete record function code:

```
//***************************************************
// delete record
//***************************************************
function deleteRecord()
{
    $uname=$_GET['deluname'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE UserName='$uname'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());



      //-------------------------------------------
      // Display notification if successful
      //-------------------------------------------
      $code = <<< htmlcode
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <p align="center" border=0 style="font-family:verdana,helvetica; font-size:15px; color:green"> 
                User successfully deleted.
          </p>
          <br/>
          <center>
            <form name="frmDataEntry" method="POST" action="" style="font-family:verdana,helvetica; font-size:12px;">
              <table border=0 style="font-family:verdana,helvetica; font-size:12px;">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="btnBack" value="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp OK &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" onClick ="frmDataEntry.action='DataEntry_List_Search.php'"/>                  
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>    
            </form>
          </center>
          <br/>
          <br/>
htmlcode;

    return $code;

}
```

Comment: off topic: beware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are obsolete. Recommend using one of PHP's more modern database APIs, such as the PDO library.

Comment: how this page is calling?

Comment: Also, please note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection hacks because you're not escaping your input variables (ie `$uname`).

Comment: please post the delete form

Comment: Why don't you use client code (Javascript) for the confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

Calling code is not visible here, but typically you just need a Javascript confirm()-function:

```
<form action="delete.php" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete user?');">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your form and delete Only i added line in form on submit

```
//***************************************************
// delete record
//***************************************************
function deleteRecord()
{
    $uname=$_GET['deluname'];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE UserName='$uname'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());



      //-------------------------------------------
      // Display notification if successful
      //-------------------------------------------
      $code = <<< htmlcode
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <p align="center" border=0 style="font-family:verdana,helvetica; font-size:15px; color:green"> 
                User successfully deleted.
          </p>
          <br/>
          <center>
            <form name="frmDataEntry" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to delete??');"> style="font-family:verdana,helvetica; font-size:12px;">
              <table border=0 style="font-family:verdana,helvetica; font-size:12px;">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="btnBack" value="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp OK &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" onClick ="frmDataEntry.action='DataEntry_List_Search.php'"/>                  
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>    
            </form>
          </center>
          <br/>
          <br/>
htmlcode;

    return $code;

}
```